# Linked list execution clarification

Tags: java, linked-list

I am facing an weird issue while executing a linked list code. I was practicing linked list and tried to execute a program to get the 3rd element from end of linked list. Code is as follows:-

```
public class FindThirdElemFromEnd {
    static int loopCounter = 0;
    static Node linkedList;
    
    static class Node {
        int data;
        Node next;
        
        public Node(int data) {
            this.data = data;
            this.next = null;
        }
    }

    public static int findNthElemFromEnd(Node firstNode, int positionFromEnd) {
        Node tempNode = firstNode;
        
        while(tempNode.next != null) {
            loopCounter = loopCounter + 1;
            
            if(loopCounter > (positionFromEnd - 1)) {
                linkedList = linkedList.next;
            }

            findNthElemFromEnd(tempNode.next, positionFromEnd);     --> Execution comes here after return executed  
        }
        
        return linkedList.data;
    }
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Node firstNode = new Node(5);
        
        Node secondNode = new Node(10);
        firstNode.next = secondNode;
        
        Node thirdNode = new Node(15);
        secondNode.next = thirdNode;
        
        Node fourthNode = new Node(20);
        thirdNode.next = fourthNode;        
        
        Node fifthNode = new Node(25);
        fourthNode.next = fifthNode;
        
        Node sixthNode = new Node(30);
        fifthNode.next = sixthNode;

        linkedList = firstNode;
        
        int nthElementData = findNthElemFromEnd(firstNode, 3);
        System.out.println(nthElementData);
    }
}
```

The issue here is:- I am able to get the 3rd element from the end of the linked list as expected. But after the return statement getting executed at "findNthElemFromEnd" method, it again starts its execution from "findNthElemFromEnd"(Denoted by:- Execution comes here after return executed) with the 3rd element from parent linkedList. Not sure, why it executes the function once again after return statement is called.

Could someone please explain why this happens.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> why it executes the function once again after return statement is called.

That is because the recursive function call happens within a `while` loop, and the condition of the `while` loop has not changed, so it will loop again, and make the recursive call again.

> I am able to get the 3rd element from the end of the linked list as expected.

The value that is returned by the recursive call is ignored. Instead it should be returned, which also means there is no reason to have a `while` loop at all. This is the decision to take here: either have a loop and no recursion, or have no loop, and use recursion.

#### Correction

To stick with your idea, you could correct by turning the `while` into an `if`, and returning the value that comes from the recursive call:

```
    public static int findNthElemFromEnd(Node firstNode, int positionFromEnd) {
        Node tempNode = firstNode;
        
        if (tempNode.next != null) {
            loopCounter = loopCounter + 1;
            
            if(loopCounter > (positionFromEnd - 1)) {
                linkedList = linkedList.next;
            }

            return findNthElemFromEnd(tempNode.next, positionFromEnd); 
        }
        
        return linkedList.data; // base case
    }
```

However, there are some downsides to this solution:

- The function relies on side-effects: `linkedList` and `loopCounter` are non local variables which this function updates. That means if you want to use that function again, you need to first reset those variables. That is not a nice pattern. It would be better to solve this with local variables only.
- Recursion costs stack space, and therefor this function puts a limit on the size of the linked list, as for bigger lists, this function will run into a stack overflow.
- It doesn't work when the list is empty (exception will be raised). It should check whether `firstNode` is `null` and act accordingly.
- It doesn't give the correct result when the value of `positionFromEnd` is greater than the size of the list. It should then not return the first node of the list, but better `null`.

The *iterative* solution is also to have two node references that are as many nodes apart as you want to stay away from the end of the list. In the first iterations of the loop the reference at the front gets to walk ahead with the required number of steps. In the rest of the iterations both references walk in tandem until the first one hits the end of the list.

Implementation:

```
    public static int findNthElemFromEnd(Node firstNode, int positionFromEnd) {
        Node frontNode = firstNode;
        Node backNode = firstNode;
        while (frontNode != null) {
            frontNode = frontNode.next;
            positionFromEnd--;
            if (positionFromEnd < 0) backNode = backNode.next;
        }
        if (positionFromEnd > 0) return null; // List is too short
        return frontNode.data;
    }
```